# Code igniter shopping cart joining and selecting from multiple tables

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, shopping-cart, multiple-tables

I'm learning code igniter and I'm currently trying to create a shopping cart that works over multiple tables. I can make it so it works using 1 table but when I try the JOIN method it always gives "Product does not exist".

The model I'm using is:

```
class Cart_model extends CI_Model {
function tvs(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tvs');
    return $query->result_array();
}
function computers(){
    $query = $this->db->get('computers');
    return $query->result_array();
}       
function laptops(){
    $query = $this->db->get('laptops');
    return $query->result_array();
}
function validate_update_cart(){
    $total = $this->cart->total_items();
    $item = $this->input->post('rowid');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    for($i=0;$i < count($item);$i++) 
    {
        $data = array(
           'rowid' => $item[$i],
           'qty'   => $qty[$i]
        );        
        $this->cart->update($data);
    }
}
function validate_add_cart_item(){
    $id = $this->input->post('product_id'); // Assign posted product_id to $id
    $qty = $this->input->post('quantity'); // Assign posted quantity to $cty
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tvs');
    $this->db->join('computers', 'computer.id = tv.id and computer.name = tv.name and   computer.price = tv.price');
    $this->db->join('laptops', 'laptops.id = tv.id and laptops.name = tv.name and laptops.price = tv.price');
    $this->db->where('tvs.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item) {
if($item['id'] == $id) {
$data = array(
'rowid' => $item['rowid'],
'qty' => $item['qty'] + $qty
);
$this->cart->update($data);
return TRUE;
}
}
$row = $query->row();
$data = array(
'id' => $id,
'qty' => $qty,
'price' => $row->price,
'name' => $row->name
);
this->cart->insert($data);
return TRUE;
{
}else{
return FALSE;
}
}
}
```

This is the item list:

```
<ul class="products">    
<?php foreach($TV as $p): ?>  
    <li>  
        <h1>
<a href="<?php echo current_url();?>/
<?php echo $p['link']; ?>" />
<?php echo $p['name']; ?>
</a>
</h1>
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/image/products/<?php echo $p['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $p['name']; ?>" /> 
<h3>
<?php echo $p['description']; ?>
</h3>
<small>&pound;<?php echo $p['price']; ?></small>  
<?php echo form_open('/testcart/home/add_cart_item'); ?>  
<fieldset>  
                <label>Quantity</label>  
                <?php echo form_input('quantity', '1', 'maxlength="2"'); ?>  
                <?php echo form_hidden('product_id', $p['id']); ?>  
                <?php echo form_submit('add', 'Add to Cart'); ?>  
            </fieldset>  
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>   
    </li>  
    <?php endforeach;?>  
</ul>`
```

Controller:

```
function add_cart_item(){    
if($this->cart_model->validate_add_cart_item() == TRUE){    
        if($this->input->post('ajax') != '1'){    
            redirect('');    
        }else{    
            echo 'true';     
        }
    }
}
```

The javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var link = baseurl;


$("ul.products form").submit(function() {
    // Get the product ID and the quantity 
    var id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
    var qty = $(this).find('input[name=quantity]').val();

     $.post(link + "home/add_cart_item", { product_id: id, quantity: qty, ajax: '1' },
        function(data){

        if(data == 'true'){

            $.get(link + "home/show_cart", function(cart){
                $("#cart_content").html(cart);
            });

        }else{
            alert("Product does not exist");
        }   

     }); 

    return false;
});

$(".empty").live("click", function(){
    $.get(link + "home/empty_cart", function(){
        $.get(link + "home/show_cart", function(cart){
            $("#cart_content").html(cart);
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

I'm not too sure where it's going wrong as I'm relatively new to all this, whether it's the Javascript or the PHP.

Comment: you do realize this return $query->result(); will exit your model function. WHat is the foreach that comes after that? Did you mean to put in another function?

Comment: Don't know what the query->result was doing there. The foreach is for when you click on add to cart the second time it will update the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error free method. You were making mistake selecting from table tvs and using tv in joins

```
function validate_add_cart_item()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('product_id'); // Assign posted product_id to $id
    $qty = $this->input->post('quantity'); // Assign posted quantity to $cty

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tvs as tv');
    $this->db->join('computers', 'computer.id = tv.id and computer.name = tv.name and   computer.price = tv.price');
    $this->db->join('laptops', 'laptops.id = tv.id and laptops.name = tv.name and laptops.price = tv.price');
    $this->db->where('tv.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Good spot! Changed it and it still gives "Product doesn't exist" however :(.

Comment: sorry but there are other problems too. read codeigniter user guide also read Jamie Rumbelows Codeigniter Hand Book this will give you a lot of help